# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}$ converge?
Well since $-1\leq \cos{(n^2)}\leq 1$ and $-1\leq \sin{(n+1)}\leq 1$, then $
\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}\leq \frac{2}{1+5^n}$. The latter converges so the original series converges by the comparison test. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: No. Comparison test generally fails for series whose terms have undetermined signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\left|\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n} \right| \leqslant \frac{|\cos{(n^2)}|+|\sin{(n+1)}|}{1+5^n} \leqslant \frac{2}{1+5^n} < \frac{2}{5^n}$$

Since $\sum 5^{-n}$ is a convergent geometric series, the series in question is **absolutely convergent** by the comparison test -- and, hence, convergent.

**Absolute convergence $\implies$ convergence as a consequence of the Cauchy criterion:**

If $\sum |a_n|$ converges then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $m > n > N$,

$$\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k\right| \leqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k| < \epsilon,$$

and, thus $\sum a_n$ converges by the Cauchy criterion.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that

$$\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}\leq \frac{2}{1+5^n}$$

but comparison test fails because $\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}$ has not constant sign.

Absolute convergence is of course the most effective method to use in this case.

Anyway, if we want use comparison test, just note that

$$-\frac{2}{1+5^n}\le\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}\leq \frac{2}{1+5^n}$$

and then

$$0\le\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}+\frac{2}{1+5^n}\leq \frac{4}{1+5^n}$$

therefore we can now apply comparison test to $\sum \left(\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}+\frac{2}{1+5^n}\right)$ which is then convergent.

From here we can conclude that also the givan series is convergent since

$$\sum \left(\frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}+\frac{2}{1+5^n}\right)=\sum \frac{\cos{(n^2)}+\sin{(n+1)}}{1+5^n}+\sum \frac{2}{1+5^n}$$